# "se se" in Portuguese

Tags: pronouns, portuguese

In Portuguese it occurs a phenomenon of *se* word repetition. The first *se* is translated to English as *if*, and the second is the reflexive pronoun of the singular 3rd person, as the last word of the following sentences:

- He washes himself
- She washes herself
- It washes itself

Examples:

**Portuguese phrase — Literal English translation — English meaning**

- Se se investir em ouro, a empresa ganha dinheiro — If itself invest in gold, the company earns money — If we invest in gold, the company earns money
- Evitar apertos de mão, mesmo se se trata de mãos lavadas — Avoid handshakes, even if itself treats about washed hands — Avoid handshakes, even if it is about washed hands

What is the name of this phenomenon? Does it occur in other languages?

Answer (score 3):

It is a case of two or more homonyms (or homographs) accidentally occurring next to each other. I do not think there is a name for it, but it occurs in all languages and is quite banal. An English example: THE POLISH POLISH POLISH BOOTS WITH POLISH POLISH.

Comment: Or "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo", repeating "buffalo" and randomizing the capitalization as many times as needed. (buffalo (n.) = bison, buffalo (v.) = bully, Buffalo (adj.) = from Buffalo, New York)